# Perl's rename - how to append a counter?

Tags: perl, rename, batch-rename

There's a nice [renaming utility](http://www.evolt.org/renaming_files_with_perl), which comes with Perl's installation. How one would append a counter in the Perl regexp? This is a relevant question e.g. for a problem of numbering files in the current directory:

```
rename 's/^/<here I'd like to have a number of a file being processed>/g' *
```

For example how would one rename:

```
fileA
fileB
fileC
```

to

```
1 - fileA
2 - fileB
3 - fileC
```

**Edit**:

I've added the counter feature (`$c` variable) - see [here](https://github.com/bk322/bk-goodies/blob/master/rename.pl). It works fine - but when I try to specify the counter format:

```
rename_c.pl -c 5.2f 's/^/$c - /' *
```

it says:

```
 Useless use of concatenation (.) or string in void context at line 120.
```

and it doesn't really use the format I told it to use. This must be some simple syntax mistake in a line number 120. Can You please take a look?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line of code in question is:

```
$c = sprintf(eval("%" . "$form", $cNumber));
```

You don't want the `eval` there; you can simply create the format as a string:

```
$c = sprintf("%$form", $cNumber));
```

The string (first argument) ends up containing the format requested, and `sprintf()` formats `$cNumber` using that.

Answer (score 4):

The basic rename utility can handle that situation just fine:

```
$ rename '$_ = sprintf "%d - %s", ++$count, $_' files...
```

Comment: I did that and perl replied: `/usr/bin/rename: can't compile perlexpr $_ = sprintf "%d - %s", ++$count, $_: Global symbol "$count" requires explicit package name`.

Comment: My rename doesn't do that.  I suppose writing `$::count` instead of just `$count` should fix that error.

Comment: It's just that your version of rename evaluates the renaming expression with strictness enabled, and mine doesn't.

Comment: Oh... That explains it. It's nice to be aware.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on macOS and using tool installed via `brew install rename`, then following should work:

```sh
rename -N ...01 -X -e '$_ = "${_}-counter-$N"' your_files
```

Example:

```sh
> rename -n -N ...01 -X -e '$_ = "${_}-counter-$N"' *.png
'iPad-Pro12.9-4g at 11.24.52.png' would be renamed to 'iPad-Pro12.9-4g at 11.24.52-counter-01.png'
'iPad-Pro12.9-4g at 11.25.09.png' would be renamed to 'iPad-Pro12.9-4g at 11.25.09-counter-02.png'
'iPad-Pro12.9-4g at 11.25.17.png' would be renamed to 'iPad-Pro12.9-4g at 11.25.17-counter-03.png'
```

Answer (score 1):

**perl one-liner** if you have access to **perl** itself

**dry run** over list of `txt` files

```
perl -le '($old=$_) && s/^/++$n."-$`"/eg && print for <*.txt>'
```

**rename**

```
perl -le '($old=$_) && s/^/++$n."-$`"/eg && rename($old,$_) for <*.txt>'
```

---

- `perl -le` run a one-liner
- `($old=$_)` save the old name
- **s/^/++$n."-$`"/eg** do the substitution | note that it has a back-tick

  - `/^/` match the begging
  - `++$n` start a counter from 1
  - *."-$`"* append counter to this
  - `/eg` run globally and `e` is for evaluation
- `rename($old,$_)` rename the `$old` => `$_`
- `for <*.txt>` loop over list of `txt` file

**You can rename everything with this pattern** and for advanced renaming you may want to use `sprintf` as well.

screenshot

[image]